# How can I open PowerShell via AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, autohotkey

I'm running AutoHotkey 1.0.48.05 on Windows 7.

I'd like CTRL-ALT-P to open PowerShell.

This is what I have so far:

```
^!p::
    Run %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Return
```

This is the error I get:

> File C:\Users[username]\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.

I've already set the execution policy to RemoteSigned by opening PowerShell ISE as Administrator and running `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. (See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx)

How can I get around this problem?

**UPDATE: In Windows 10, I don't even need AutoHotKey for this.** Instead, I can press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, then Yes.

Comment: aaht happens if you manually run `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`?

Comment: PowerShell opens (but for some reason it's black instead of blue when I open it this way)

Comment: Thats what it looks like when you run it in cmd.exe

Comment: Have you tried setting the execution policy to something less restrictive. RemoteSigned perhaps? In a powershell session: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Comment: yes, as my question says

Comment: Ooops...reading comprehension for FTW...sorry about that.

Comment: I will point out however that if you are in a 64 bit version of windows, you would need to set the execution policy for both 64 bit powershell and 32 bit just to be sure that wasn't it.

Comment: This seemed to work!  My PowerShell window is black instead of blue, but I bet everything else is the same. If you write this as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Ryan I submitted his answer as a community wiki. Feel free to mark it as correct and make the internet a better place!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in a 64 bit version of windows, you would need to set the execution policy for both 64 bit powershell and 32 bit.

This means you need to run the same command in both a 32-bit powershell session and 64-bit powershell session. For 32-bit powershell, just search for "Windows Powershell (x86)" in the Start menu.

Comment: Good call, didn't know this.

Comment: Ok how do you do that?  I only see one version of the command in the other answers?

Comment: @Lee You need to run the same command in both a 32-bit powershell session and 64-bit powershell session. For 32-bit powershell, just search for  "Windows Powershell (x86)" in the Start menu.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same issue.  Instead of changing my execution policy for all scripts, I went with this:

```
#p::
^!p::
EnvGet, SystemRoot, SystemRoot
Run %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted,
return
```